# Background color of NSGridview

Tags: swift, cocoa, appkit

I tried to set the background color of an `NSGridView` by subclassing it and overriding its `draw` method like this:

```
class GridViewGreen: NSGridView
{ override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)
  { super.draw(dirtyRect)

    let color = NSColor.green
    let bp = NSBezierPath(rect: dirtyRect)
    color.set()
    bp.stroke()

    print("drawing GridViewGreen")
  }
}
```

But the `draw` method is never called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: Preferably take catlan's answer if possible. He is right in that NSGridView isn't really meant for rendering and this approach will more or less force it down that path.

At this point, pretty much every Cocoa application should be layer-backing their views and NSGridView and NSStackView aren't any different. Simply set the background color on the layer.

```
let gridView = NSGridView(views: [[view1, view2]])
gridView.wantsLayer = true
gridView.layer?.backgroundColor = NSColor.red.cgColor
```

Comment: what´s the disadvantage of using layer-backed views, because it´s off by default?

Comment: @mik Having the backing layer uses more memory, but many components in AppKit now require it for animation performance purposes (like the newer NSCollectionView).

Answer (score 5):

`NSGridView`is a lightweight component, like `NSStackView`, for layout only. Because of this it doesn't draw.

Just put the `NSGridView` into an `NSBox` and set its `fillColor`.

Comment: I find this info quit usefull. Better then to dig around with layer to do a simple thing.

Answer (score 0):

NSGridView is a subclass of NSView so it inherits all of NSView's properties and methods *including* drawing - as seen in the `draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect)` function. Make sure to include an IBOutlet in your view controller or change the `NSGridView` class in Interface Builder to GridViewGreen.

```
class GridViewGreen: NSGridView {
    override init(frame frameRect: NSRect) {
        super.init(frame: frameRect)
    }
    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: coder)
    }
    override func draw(_ dirtyRect: NSRect) {
        super.draw(dirtyRect)
        NSColor.green.setFill()
        dirtyRect.fill()
        print("drawing GridViewGreen")
    }
}
```

Basically your view controller doesn't know that you subclassed your grid view.